# "Sign in with Apple" web flow - custom icon when having multiple apps

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in, apple-id, sign-in-with-apple

I am implementing Sign in with Apple for a organization having a bunch of apps.

I want to have a single Service Id for all these apps (and group them all under the same group id), in order to have a single app authorization flow (+ a single email per user for all the apps, even if its a private-relay one)

**How can I set a custom icon in the web flow + iPhone config?**

I already tried using a 'fake' demo app as a primary (as suggested in an [Apple forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123054)), with an icon representing my whole organization instead of a specific app

=> but that isn't working, possibly because I only pushed it to Testflight and not the AppStore (again, this is an fake/empty demo app)

Did anyone face and/or was able to work around this issue? Apple doesn't offer extensive documentation for this use case

---

Here are screenshots to visualize the issue:

- Web flow:
  [image: web flow]
- iPhone config:
  [image]

Comment: I'm in the same trouble now. Did you find any solution?

Comment: hey @cafedeichi, unfortunately not really... we had to chose one of our app and make it primary

Comment: ok thx! hoping we could find some improvements in WWDC next week :)